# CodeKit / JADE escape HTML snippet

Tags: pug, codekit

I'm writing a documentation for a CSS framework and I want to include HTML snippets on the page.

I have tried several filters, but they does not seem to work with CodeKit out of the box:

````
:markdown
    ```
    hello<b>world</b>
    ```
````

(custom markdown parser required)

```
:escape
    hello<b>world</b>
```

(unknown filter :escape)

```
:plain
    hello<b>world</b>
```

(unknown filter :plain)

What managed to somewhat work:

```
pre
    ='hello<b>world</b>'
```

but it's still not straightforward. Is there a standard way to include and escape a perforated HTML block form inside JADE template without hacking around standard CodeKit distribution?

Comment: How about [`|`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text) instead of [`=`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code)

Comment: It's not escaping <html> elements